# How to get distinct values from set of rows matching condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I have a table of following nature.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
| Id | AccountId | ProjectId | Year | Quarter | Data |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
| 39 |       163 |        60 | 2019 |       2 |    0 |
| 40 |       163 |        60 | 2019 |       2 |    8 |
| 41 |       163 |        61 | 2019 |       2 |    1 |
| 42 |       163 |        61 | 2019 |       2 |    2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------+
```

I want to get distinct `ProjectIds` as Json using Entity Framework, so far my code looks like this.

```
    // GET: api/Insight/163/2019/2
    [HttpGet("{accid}/{year}/{qurter}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSurveys([FromRoute] long accid, [FromRoute] long year, [FromRoute] long qurter)
    {
        //This code gives me the error.
        return await _context.CustomerSatisfactionResults.Select(x=>x.ProjectId)
            .Where(x => x.AccountId == accid && x.Year == year && x.Quarter == qurter).ToListAsync();
    }
```

When I hit this endpoint with parameters, `/163/2019/2` I want a Json responce as,

```
[
  "60", "61"
]
```

But I get the following error.
[image]
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Does the query return data?  If you get null then you will get an exception.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to confirm the response has good data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an error is because you apply the `Where` condition on a projected sequence that includes only `ProjectId`. You should use `Where` before `Select`.

To get the distinct values, use the [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
return await _context.CustomerSatisfactionResults
   .Where(x => x.AccountId == accid && x.Year == year && x.Quarter == qurter)
   .Select(x => x.ProjectId)
   .Distinct()
   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you, That was helpful. :)